# The matrix of the bilinear form $g = \epsilon ^1 \otimes \epsilon ^2 + 2 \epsilon ^2 \otimes \epsilon ^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors, bilinear-form

If I have some simple bilinear form (tensor) example given as:

$g = \epsilon ^1 \otimes \epsilon ^2 + 2 \epsilon ^2 \otimes \epsilon ^2$

The epsilons denote vectors (covectors) of the dual basis $K^*$.

The matrix of the bilinear form is:

$$[g]_K = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$

But the coefficients of the matrix $[g]_K$ have actually lower indices, like:

$$[g]_K = \begin{pmatrix} g_{11} & g_{12} \\ g_{21} & g_{22} \end{pmatrix}$$

Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: I am asking about the lower/upper indices. I encountared one solved problem I didnt understand because of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indices in the coefficients come from the objects where you evaluate the tensor on. Since $g$ is covariant, it eats vectors. If $(e_1,e_2)$ are dual to $(\epsilon^1, \epsilon^2)$, you can evaluate $g_{ij} = g(e_i,e_j)$, but not $g^{ij} = g(\epsilon^1,\epsilon^2)$, as the latter a priori does not make sense. Then $$\begin{align} g_{11} &= g(e_1,e_1) = (\epsilon^1\otimes \epsilon^2)(e_1,e_1) + 2(\epsilon^2\otimes \epsilon^2)(e_1,e_1) \\ &=  \epsilon^1(e_1)\epsilon^2(e_2) + 2\epsilon^2(e_1)\epsilon^2(e_1) \\ &= 1\cdot 0 + 2 \cdot 0 \cdot  0 \\ &= 0,\end{align}$$and similarly for the others.

If instead you had something contravariant like $h = e_1\otimes e_1\otimes e_2$, it would make sense (under the natural identification between a finite-dimensional vector space and its bidual) to evaluate $h$ in covectors, so that, for example, $$h^{112} = h(\epsilon^1,\epsilon^1,\epsilon^2) = (e_1\otimes e_1\otimes e_2)(\epsilon^1,\epsilon^1,\epsilon^2) = \epsilon^1(e_1)\epsilon^1(e_1)\epsilon^2(e_2) = 1\cdot 1 \cdot 1 = 1,$$while $h^{122} = 0$, etc..

Comment: Yeah, so because I have a bilinear form I need to get a number as a result. So my upper indices are needed to be eaten by lower indices. I have rewritten it as a scalar product and is better for me to visualize it. Is it ok? And thank you for the answer.

Comment: You should not think of an inner product here. It can cause confusion, because with an inner product you can identify vectors and covectors and make sense of $g^{ij}$ (there's an abuse of notation going on here and I don't want to go into this now -- this is the reason why I said _a priori does not make sense_ in the answer -- because later it does). The only information you need to evaluate these things now is $\epsilon^i(e_j) = \delta^i_j$.

Comment: Also, one more thing you may find instructive. Say $A$ is a linear operator, with $Ae_j = a^i_{~j}e_i$, so that $(a^i_{~j})$ is the matrix of $A$ with respect to the basis $(e_i)$. The operator $A$ is identified with the $(1,1)$-tensor $a^i_{~j} e_i\otimes \epsilon^j$. The index balance required by this identification is the reason why sometimes people denote matrices with one upper index and one lower index.